# Function not executing, something must be wrong

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

I am doing an assignment for class and my code is working great up until the point where I call the function `getTaxRate`. Everything displays fine before then, but with `getTaxRate`, nothing. It feels like nothing is getting passed to the function, or I'm typing something in wrong. But I've been staring at this for so long that everything looks the same now. So please, any helpful comments are welcomed.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Matthew Young </title>
    <script language ="JavaScript">
    const RATE_ONE = .10;
    const RATE_TWO = .15;
    const RATE_THREE = .25;
    const RATE_FOUR = .28;
    const RATE_FIVE = .33;
    const RATE_SIX = .35;
    const RATE_SEVEN = .396;

function getTaxRate(inIncome) {
    var taxRate;
    var taxIncome = parseInt(inIncome);
    if (taxIncome >= 0 && taxIncome <= 8925)
    {
        taxRate = RATE_ONE;
    }
    if else (taxIncome >= 8926 && taxIncome <= 36250)
    {
        taxRate = RATE_TWO;
    }
    if else (taxIncome >= 36251 && taxIncome <= 87850)
    {
        taxRate = RATE_THREE;
    }
    if else (taxIncome >= 87851 && taxIncome <= 183250)
    {
        taxRate = RATE_FOUR;
    }
    if else (taxIncome >= 183251 && taxIncome <= 398350)
    {
        taxRate = RATE_FIVE;
    }
    if else (taxIncome >= 398351 && taxIncome <= 400000)
    {
        taxRate = RATE_SIX;
    }
    else (taxIncome >= 400001)
    {
        taxRate = RATE_SEVEN;
    }
    return taxRate;
}

function calculateTaxes(inTaxableIncome, inTaxRate) {
    var income = parseInt(inTaxableIncome);
    var rate = parseFloat(inTaxRate);
    var owed = intaxableIncome * inTaxRate;

    return owed;
}

function refundOrPay(inTaxesOwed, inTaxesPaid) {
    var owed = parseInt(inTaxesOwed);
    var paid = parseInt(inTaxesPaid);
    var taxDifference = owed - paid;

    return taxDifference;
}
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script language ="JavaScript">
        document.writeln("Welcome to COP 2500 Tax Services!");
        var taxIncome = prompt("Enter your year-end income: ");
        var deduction = prompt("Enter your taxable deduction: ");

        var taxableIncome = parseInt(taxIncome) - parseInt(deduction);  
        document.writeln("<br>Your taxable income is " + taxableIncome);

        var rate = getTaxRate(taxableIncome);
        document.writeln("Based on a taxable income of " +taxableIncome+ "your tax rate is " +rate * 100+ "percent<br>");


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a debugger. Please use it.

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? Staring is not debugging. Tip: `if else` looks very wrong: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Description

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. At the *very least* try logging to the console to see what is going on.

Comment: For javascript pless f12 in your browser, and try http://jshint.com/

Comment: I apologize. I am in no way looking for the easy way out. I have not debugged anything in a while. I am using notepad++. Does that come with a debugger?

Comment: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: @MatthewYoung You can debug the code in your browser. Be aware that `const` was a Mozilla-specific extension and it will be defined (differently) in ES6, so it may be unsafe to use.

Comment: +1 for the astute observation (Function not executing, something must be wrong) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in "if else". You need to use like "else if". Update your function like below.

```
function getTaxRate(inIncome) {
var taxRate;
var taxIncome = parseInt(inIncome);
if (taxIncome >= 0 && taxIncome <= 8925)
{
    taxRate = RATE_ONE;
}
else if (taxIncome >= 8926 && taxIncome <= 36250)
{
    taxRate = RATE_TWO;
}
else if(taxIncome >= 36251 && taxIncome <= 87850)
{
    taxRate = RATE_THREE;
}
else if(taxIncome >= 87851 && taxIncome <= 183250)
{
    taxRate = RATE_FOUR;
}
else if(taxIncome >= 183251 && taxIncome <= 398350)
{
    taxRate = RATE_FIVE;
}
else if(taxIncome >= 398351 && taxIncome <= 400000)
{
    taxRate = RATE_SIX;
}
else (taxIncome >= 400001)
{
    taxRate = RATE_SEVEN;
}
return taxRate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I JUST noticed that. I feel so dumb. Thank you again!